# Overflow, float ,height Mess

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I am using a Navigation design from the site -  [CSSDECK](http://cssdeck.com/labs/flashy-navigation-with-rollover-effect).

I have done some modification and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/knoxxs/RAX3a/13/) is my code.

**DOUBTS:**

1. Why `#siteNav` and `#siteNav ul` not wrapping around `li`s. I have used `height:auto` in `#siteNav` and `#siteNav ul`. What I know is `auto` means browser will decide the height **accordingly**. But this isn't happening. *WHY?*
2. If I do `overflow:auto or hidden` in any of `#siteNav` or `#siteNav ul`. Then that block wrap itself around the `li`s. Why using `overflow` doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `li`s are floated. When you don't have `overflow: hidden;`, then the `li`s are in a different context than the `ul`, so the `ul` doesn't wrap around them.

`overflow: hidden;` is a generic, known fix for containers to resize to fit their `float`ed contents, but there are other methods -- for an extensive reference, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/364869).

Comment: yeah! I am also feeling like the same that's why I have title it `float mess`. But as you said `li `s are in a different context. Can you explain or share any resource which simply explain this context.

Comment: @knoxxs The context is just the "floating context." Unfloated elements kind of "don't see" floated elements. For more explanation on the several methods, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

just apply `overflow: hidden;` to your  `#siteNav ul`

```
 #siteNav ul {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Because you establish a new Block Formatting Context when using overflow with anything ofther then visible (link to the [w3.org specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)). ***by- ChristopheD***

[read this](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)

Comment: I think the OP already knows that `overflow: hidden;` **fixes** the issue, he/she would rather to find out **why**.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because lis are floated. Any wrapper containing floated elements will not wrap the contents unless overflow: hidden is applied to the wrapper.This is a common browser issue with floated elements. Also, overflow:hidden does not fix this issue in all browsers. Search for "clearfix" to see cross browser fix for this issue.

BTW, you don't need the height:auto there, block elements by default have width and height auto. If there was no floated element inside, then you would see the expected behavior.